# kafka async commit request failing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have observed that the kafka consumer lag suddenly starts increasing after few hours/days running.

Upon checking the logs, I see alot of exception:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.

My ConsumerThread class:

```
public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable {
  private final KafkaConsumer<String, Map<String, Object>> consumer;
  public ConsumerThread(
    this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getConsumerConfig(kafkaConfiguration));
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      consumer.subscribe(topicList);

      while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, Map<String, Object>> records =
            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(kafkaConfiguration.getPollIntervalMs()));

        long startPerPoll = System.nanoTime();
        for (final ConsumerRecord<String, Map<String, Object>> record : records) {
            // message processing logic here
        }


        consumer.commitAsync((offsets, exception) -> {
            if (exception != null) {
              //log.error(exception.getMessage());
              log.info("exception while committing offset, consumerThread: {}, exception: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), exception);
              exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ignore for shutdown
      log.info("exception in run for consumerThread: {}", e);
    } finally {
      try {
        if (Objects.nonNull(consumer)) {
          consumer.commitSync();
        }
      } finally {
        if (Objects.nonNull(consumer)) {
          consumer.close();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

My kafka configuration:

```
groupId: cep-cg
autoCommitEnabled: false
sessionTimeoutMs: 30000
heartBeatIntervalMs: 10000
autoOffsetReset: latest
maxPollRecord: 250
maxPollIntervalMs: 180000
requestTimeoutMs: 240000
pollIntervalMs: 3000
```

I checked other answers on stackoverflow and made few tweaks but none of them seems to work.

What I want to know is:

1. Any leads on why the lag could be increasing suddenly ?
2. Is it possible alot of commitAsync request is pending on the broker and maybe some time (defined by some config on broker), the commitAsync request starts to fail ?
3. Let's say a consumerThread took more that `max.poll.interval.ms` time to process the message. In this case, it would be kicked out of the group and the re-balance is triggered. Now all the `commitAsync` request pending on broker fails with `CommitFailedException` since the partition now belongs to some other consumer in group.  In the above code, the consumer would break out of infinite loop and will be closed forever. Is this correct way ? Or should I catch `CommitFailedException` and again resume the loop to keep the consumer alive ?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that we sent a request to commit offset 2000. There is a temporary communication problem, so the broker never gets the request and therefore never responds. Meanwhile,
we processed another batch and successfully committed offset 3000.now retries the previously batches failed commit and in the exception , it is displaying the same message.In the case of rebalance, this will cause more duplicates

**A. Lag time is increasing**

As the rebalance is happening more frequently due to which consumer is not consuming the records constantly but producer is constantly producing the records.

**B. commitAsync request timeout**

Only active members of the group are allowed to commit offsets. If the consumer has been kicked out of the group when it tries to commit a offset , it will throw CommitFailedException

**c.Rebalance**

When a rebalance begins, the consumer must finish whatever processing it is currently doing, commit offsets, and rejoin the group before the session timeout expires.

We should impement the consumerRebalanceListener and use onPartitionsRevoked() to commit offsets before losing ownership of a partition to commit the current offset.

**max.poll.interval.ms** and **max.poll.records** to a fairly low value while also keeping session.timeout.ms low so that failure detection time didn't need to be sacrificed.

CommitFailedException thrown from commitSync(). This guarantees that only active members of the group are allowed to commit offsets. If the consumer has been kicked out of the group, then its partitions will have been assigned to another member, which will be committing its own offsets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but was expecting some deeper insights into the problem rather than cherry-picking content from the book (Kafka - The definitive guide).

Comment: The concepts has been taken from kafka-definitive guide and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread.

Comment: @RohitYadav for point A, what if i pause my producer for sometime, will it prevent rebalance and also consumer can complete all messages produced by producer, then i can resume producer?  Because i see  'Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {po-line-topic-14=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=81282005, metadata=''}} failed' due to point A reason